# Why does cdk overlay data refresh require 3 clicks to refresh?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I created an angular overlay component to display information about a card from within which the overlay component is opened (by clicking an info button in the card); when opened it makes an API call to retrieve some data from an API with parameters passed on click. Current behavior takes two-three clicks to display the correct data:

- If it is the first click since page load it throws an error. (data is retrieved but not displayed. overlay doesn't open. I have pasted the error underneath)
- Second click requests data again, opens the overlay and displays the data.
- Clicking on a different card takes 3 tries to the get the correct data to display.

  - first click requests new data and opens overlay previous cards data.
  - second click on the page to close this overlay
  - third click requests new data again and opens overlay with new data.

Process flow:

> open > createOverlay > getOverlayConfig > attachDialogContainer > createInjector > TeamInfoOverlayComponent > close

Error upon first click:

> ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA -> InjectionToken TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA -> InjectionToken TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA!
>       at NullInjector.get

overlay-ref.ts

```
import { OverlayRef } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

export class TeamInfoOverlayRef {

  constructor(private overlayRef: OverlayRef) { }

  close(): void {
    this.overlayRef.dispose();
    console.log('in close');
  }
}
```

overlay.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'team-info-overlay',
  template: `
   <mat-card class="example-card"  class="mat-elevation-z5">
        <mat-card-header>Team Members</mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content *ngFor="let member of team">
            <mat-card-subtitle>
                {{member.first_name + member.last_name}}    {{member.role_name}}    {{member.email}}    {{member.total_chapters}}    {{member.added}}    {{member.tc_accepted}}
            </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-content>
   </mat-card>
    `,
    styles: [`
    :host {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }

    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 1em;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: auto;
    }

    .overlay-content {
      padding: 1em;
    }
  `]
})
export class TeamInfoOverlayComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: TeamInfoOverlayRef,
    @Inject(TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA) public team: any) {
      console.log('in TeamInfoOverlayComponent constructor');
    }
}
```

overlay.service.ts

```
interface TeamInfoDialogConfig {
  panelClass?: string;
  hasBackdrop?: boolean;
  backdropClass?: string;
  Organizers?: Organizers[];
}

const DEFAULT_CONFIG: TeamInfoDialogConfig = {
  hasBackdrop: true,
  backdropClass: 'dark-backdrop',
  panelClass: 'tm-file-preview-dialog-panel',
  Organizers: null
}

@Injectable()
export class TeamInfoOverlayService {

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private overlay: Overlay) { 
        console.log('TeamInfoOverlayService constructor');
    }

  open(config: TeamInfoDialogConfig = {}) {
      console.log('in open');
    // Override default configuration
    const dialogConfig = { ...DEFAULT_CONFIG, ...config };

    // Returns an OverlayRef which is a PortalHost
    const overlayRef = this.createOverlay(dialogConfig);

    // Instantiate remote control
    const dialogRef = new TeamInfoOverlayRef(overlayRef);

    const overlayComponent = this.attachDialogContainer(overlayRef, dialogConfig, dialogRef);

    overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => dialogRef.close());
    // overlayRef.backdropClick().(_ => dialogRef.close());

    return dialogRef;
  }

  private createOverlay(config: TeamInfoDialogConfig) {
      console.log('in createOverlay');
    const overlayConfig = this.getOverlayConfig(config);
    return this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);
  }

  private attachDialogContainer(overlayRef: OverlayRef, config: TeamInfoDialogConfig, dialogRef: TeamInfoOverlayRef) {
      console.log('in attachDialogContainer');
    const injector = this.createInjector(config, dialogRef);

    const containerPortal = new ComponentPortal(TeamInfoOverlayComponent, null, injector);
    const containerRef: ComponentRef<TeamInfoOverlayComponent> = overlayRef.attach(containerPortal);

    return containerRef.instance;
  }

  private createInjector(config: TeamInfoDialogConfig, dialogRef: TeamInfoOverlayRef): PortalInjector {
      console.log('in createInjector');
    const injectionTokens = new WeakMap();

    injectionTokens.set(TeamInfoOverlayRef, dialogRef);
    injectionTokens.set(TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA, config.Organizers);

    return new PortalInjector(this.injector, injectionTokens);
  }

  private getOverlayConfig(config: TeamInfoDialogConfig): OverlayConfig {
      console.log('in getOverlayConfig');
    const positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
      .global()
      .centerHorizontally()
      .centerVertically();

    const overlayConfig = new OverlayConfig({
      hasBackdrop: config.hasBackdrop,
      backdropClass: config.backdropClass,
    //   panelClass: config.panelClass,
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
      positionStrategy
    });

    return overlayConfig;
  }
}
```

overlay.token.ts

```
export const TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA = new InjectionToken<Organizers>('TEAM_INFO_DIALOG_DATA');
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick update here before I forget to post it .. for anyone who may possibly run into this. To give an idea of how I am invoking the modal view:

1. Component A displays numerous cards. Each card has an info icon
   upon clicking of which a modal view appears.
2. Clicking the info
   icon invokes the service for the modal which prepares the modal by
   gathering the configuration settings (this includes data returned from an api call.)

   - This is where I was running into an issue. The data would return after the configuration settings were passed to the portal host to
     configure the modal.
   - The first click on card A would be blank (call and load data). Second click on card A displayed the data. Third click on card B
     displayed card A's data. Fourth click displayed the data
     corresponding to card B.

It took me way too long to figure this out; unfortunately a few weeks. Figured it out none the less. The temporary solution is to pause the execution for a fraction of a second to allow the api to complete retrieving the data. I will post a more robust solution utilizing promises shortly.

Hope this helps who ever stumbles across this mundane issue.